# Select one of many class names

Tags: jquery

I need to get the name of the second class from an element like this:

```
<div class="item getthisclass"></div>
```

Using this will pick both classes:

```
var selectedClass = $(this).attr('class');
```

or this does not select anything.

```
$(this).not('.item').attr('class');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `this.className.split(' ')[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.split()`.

```
// Create an array of class names...
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

// Now you can grab the by index...
var firstClass = classes[0]
var secondClass = classes[1];
var thirdClass = classes[2];
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Will accept the answer as soon as I can in 10 min.

Comment: I've updated it to deal with possible extra spaces in your class attribute and a clearer example.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the `classList` object(it can also be used to add, remove or toggle classes). I find it more useful than the jQuery `attr('class')` way. Try:

`this.classList`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

Comment: Damn, seems useful. Stinks it's only supported in IE10+.